# iOS interactivePopGestureRecognizer causing views to display incorrect navigation bar

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c

I am enabling the interactivePopGestureRecognizer in viewDidAppear in this fashion :

```
   if ([self.navigationController respondsToSelector(interactivePopGestureRecognizer)]) {
       self.navigationConroller.interactivePopGestureRecognizer.enabled = YES;
       self.navigationController.interactivePopGestureRecognizer.delegate = self;
   }
```

This piece of code gets called in every pushed/popped View Controller's lifecycle. The gesture recognizer works correctly if the swipe action is completed. But if a partial swipe occurs, the view controller displays the correct view but the Navigation Bar gets misplaced/shows the earlier view controllers navigation bar. I am using custom left and right navigation bar items and not a back button.
  I've also tried placing the code in different lifecycle methods such as viewDidLoad and even tried setting the delegate to the navigation controller itself. But the result doesnt change. I tried searching for similar issues on SO but could not find a correct response. I did find one link which said that the issue could be because of calling lifecycle methods in code directly (viewDidAppear, viewWillAppear). But there is no such direct method call in the application. Other links mentioned an issue with having a custom leftBarButtonItem.
  Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Did you forget to call [super viewWillAppear] or similar for a viewcontroller subclass that is pushed onto a navigation controller. Seem to remember this can cause the problem you describe. Without the call to super appropriate layout methods are not called on the navigation item/bar.

Comment: I dont think that's the case. I have a base view controller class which implements all the lifecycle methods correctly with super calls. And the derived classes have the right calls to super as well.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into a similar problem, in which a partial swipe left the current view (call it A) with the earlier (lower on the stack) viewcontroller's navigation bar (call it B).  I solved it by including the code that configures the navigation bar in the viewDidAppear method as well as the viewWillAppear method of viewcontroller A.  Seems awkward, but it restored viewcontroller A's navigation bar when returning to A after a partial swipe. For what it's worth, I found this to be a problem only for tableviewcontrollers, and not for a standard UIViewControllers.